# Problem with preg_replace /e modifier when used in a loop

Tags: php, preg-replace

When I use following code:

```
$text = /*some text*/;
$langs = array('en', 'pl');
foreach($langs as $lang) {
    $text = preg_replace("/I18N\('(.+?)'\)/e", 'func("$1", "$lang")', $text);
}
```

preg_replace only works for the first array element ('en' in this example). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I won't answer because regular expressions are opaque to me, but It looks like you are replacing the text in the first pass, and the second pass, there's no match.

Comment: YES! thats it! post an answer and I will accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [won't] will answer though regular expressions are opaque to me: it looks like you are replacing the text in the first pass, and the second pass, there's no match